# Event code 3005 ID 1309 - IIS

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have problems with my application after last Windows Updates and ASP.NET  4.0.303.
My application has crashed after some minutes, looking in Windows Event Viewer, I found this error log, is the same who appears in my application after ASP.NET error.

Somenone, have any idea how i can resolve this?

```
(Version: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Version do ASP.NET:4.7.3062.0)

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/20/2018 9:49:32 AM 
Event time (UTC): 7/20/2018 12:49:32 PM 
Event ID: 3289371ae4054ebf8cf135d6d4e0689e 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-10-131765645707725685 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Aplication\ 
Machine name: SRV02

Process information: 
Process ID: 4560 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
Exception type: MissingMethodException 
Exception message: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Owin.Logging.AppBuilderLoggerExtensions.SetLoggerFactory(Owin.IAppBuilder, Microsoft.Owin.Logging.ILoggerFactory)'.
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

User: 
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type: 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 71 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace: at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1 startup)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint()
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web application does not require the last .NET Framework update that got installed, please remove it and then test your application again.

Comment: The application needs the .Net, i tried remove and reinstall .Net and was 
unsuccessfully